# Why does yosys mark used sub-modules as unused?

Tags: circuit-design, yosys

**Question:**

Why does [yosys](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/) mark used sub-modules as unused?

**Background:**

I am trying to find a **rough estimate** of the area of a circuit. Some years ago, during my bachelor's, I have used a synthesis tool. IIRC, it was Synopsys. I don't have access to it anymore, so I am using an open source alternative, **qflow**. This is the first time I have ever used it, or any of its sub-tools, so I do *not* know its intrinsics. Note, though, that I am open to using other open source tools.

**Ultimate Goal:**

Compare the area of two modules, *A* and *B*. *A* is composed of 7 (slightly different) instances of module *C*, and an instance of (an extremely simple) module *D*. *B* is composed of 16 (slightly different) instances of module *C*. It is expected that *A* is smaller than *B*.

**Detailed description of the problem**

I have tried building (synthesizing+placing+routing) A and B, as described in qflow's [documentation](http://opencircuitdesign.com/qflow/reference.html): `qflow build A` and `qflow build B`. Each module was built in its own complete project - *i.e.*, *C*'s source code has been explicitly duplicated. I have located an area dump similar to the one in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/306704/how-to-estimate-chip-area-from-verilog-design) (in `place.log`); however, the results did not make sense: *A* had roughly the same "total cell area" as *B*.

I had my suspicions that the sub-modules were not present in the final synthesis of the top modules; thus, I have built module *C* by itself (`qflow build C`). *C* was an order of magnitude larger than *A* and *B*, which confirmed my suspicions that *A* and *B* were being built without *C*. Parsing `synth.log` confirmed that the instances of *C* have been removed during the synthesis step (**yosys**) (for each *C** variation of C there was a "Removing unused module *C**"). Nonetheless, *D* had not been removed from *A* (*i.e.*, it is used). I have no idea why: my testbench files confirm that both modules *A* and *B* make use of *C* to correctly generate output (tested using iverilog).

Comment: synthesis tools might "inline" your module at a higher level. flatten designs can be optimized more aggressively, result in a smaller design. haven't worked with yosys, but some tools have switches to prevent flattening -> have you viewed the result at gate level?

Comment: No, I haven't, but it was indeed removing code, not flattening modules. I do not fully understand why it would decide to remove that code (it should at least trigger a warning), but the reason was that I had two always blocks modifying the same register. I will add an "answer" shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler decided to optimize away some code it did not like without triggering an error or warning. Basically, there were two `always` blocks operating on the same register.

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
  if (resetn) begin
    state <= 0;
  end
end

always @(posedge clock) begin
  if (!resetn) begin
    case (state)
      0: begin
        if (change_to_state_1) begin
          state <= 1;
          output <= output_from_d;
        end
      end
      1: begin
        state <= 0;
        output <= output_from_c;
      end
    endcase
  end
end
```

Since it did not like `state` being assigned a value on both `always` blocks, it seems to have removed all assignments to `state` in the second `always` block; therefore, `state` could only be 0. All non-0 states became unreachable; thus, they were optimized away. Since all references to *C* were unreachable, it was marked as unused, and, thus, removed. *D* was used as a temporary output in state 0, so it was marked as used.

The solution is to make sure no two instances of `always` blocks that occur on the same condition modify the same variable. For example, in this case one can merge the `always` blocks using an if-else statement on `resetn`.